# I am unable to initialize a data member of object by passing object as parameter

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class one
{
    public:
        int datam;
        void show()
        {
            cout<<datam;
        }
};

void addv(one par)
{ 
     par.datam=2;
}

int main()
{
    one w;
    addv(w);
    w.show();

    return 0;
}
```

After compilation this gives garbage value.  Why can't I initialize `datamember(datam)` of object `w`.
I know there are other methods to initialize but what is the problem in this method?

Comment: Definitely a dupe somewhere, but I can't find it. FYI you're looking for the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference

Comment: You are passing object `w` **by value** so the copy is actually assigned a new value, which is lost on function return.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass by [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).  See the modified code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class one
{
    public:
        int datam;
        void show()
        {
            cout<<datam;
        }
};

void addv(one &par)
{ 
     par.datam=5;
}

int main()
{
    one w;
    addv(w);
    w.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have changed the prototype of function `addv()` as:

```
void addv(one &par)
//------------^^^^
```

In your code, you are passing by value (and not reference) due to which, you get a garbage value.  Working code [**here**](http://ideone.com/VOXtlE).

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing anything by reference. To pass by reference your function should be declared as `void addv(one &par)` . So you are passing a copy and initializing the copy which gets destroyed before the function returns.